# Is Hours used as an adverb in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Authorities Say the Philippines' Most Active Volcano Could Be Just Hours From Erupting (The title of an article from Yahoo news)

I don't know whether 'Hours' functions as a noun in the place for complement or an adverb in the sentence.

I think it is used adverbly because if it is a noun, it has to modify 'the Philippines' Most Active Volcano', and then, the meaning of the sentence seems to be awkward, so, I think, it should be an adverb modifying the verb 'be'.

Comment: It's a noun. It's a predicate nominative. Volcano (subj.) could be (linking verb) hours (predicate nominative).

Comment: @joiedevivre But how come hours is to be volcano? However I think, I don't get it.

Comment: "Hours" is a **noun**, so "hours from erupting" is a noun phrase that functions as complement of "be". The NP refers to "Philippines' Most Active Volcano".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your question and the comments, all units of measurement can be used this way:

> I am two pounds away from my weight-loss goal.
> The children were miles from home.
> The bandwidth is one gigabit per second from the required speed.

It's also appropriate to use this construction with "past":

> I am two hours past the deadline.

I suppose this could be confusing, though. Obviously, the subject doesn't somehow turn into the unit of measurement. But the unit of measurement is still a noun. The entire phrase "hours from erupting" is describing the volcano, if that helps. That would make the phrase adjectival.

In fact that's probably a better way to deconstruct it than I did in the comments:

Volcano = subject
Could be = linking verb
Hours from erupting = predicate adjectival phrase

Comment: I have got it well what you say. But, how about to think the part 'two hours past the deadline' as an adverbial phrase that is modifying the verb 'be'. I think that Hours from erupting is describing a time of the future to which the volcano is related, but not the volcano as it is.

Comment: You can think of it as a predicate adjective, but a predicate adjective or nominative is required to make a complete sentence. You couldn't say, for example, "I am rarely." Rarely is an adverb that modifies the to be verb, but the sentence is not complete.

Comment: I agree with you that "I am rarely" is not a complete sentence. But it does seem not to be the case related to our discussed sentence, because it does not just make sense. And I think that 'I am two hours past the deadline' it can be a complete sentence, even if 'two hours past the deadline' were an adverbial phrase because it seems to convey the meaning well to think so.

Comment: My point was that if "two hours past the deadline" were adverbial, then the sentence would not have a subject complement, so it would be an incomplete sentence. But "two hours past the deadline" *is* the subject complement, so it describes the subject (I). Subject > linking verb > adverb is not a valid grammatical structure in English. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I couldn't agree more with you. But we can think that 'I am'(meaning 'I exist'), as it is, is a grammatically complete sentence, it is not an usual sentence to write so, though.

Comment: Except in a few weird philosophical contexts, when "I am" is used as a complete sentence, it is an ellipsis, where the subject complement is implied. For example: Are you hungry? Yes, I am (hungry). Is the volcano about to erupt? It is (about to erupt). You still couldn't put an adverb in there without knowing the context: Are you leaving? Yes, I am, happily (leaving). In fact, happily actually modifies the implied verb "leaving," rather than the stated verb "am."

Comment: Then, there seems to be no better way to explain the sentence clearly except your explaination.

Comment: "Hours" is a noun, not an adjective, so "hours from erupting" can only be a noun phrase. The PP "from erupting" is complement to "hours", and the NP functions as complement of "be".